# Is there any way to consume multiple service bus messages at a time in the service bus-triggered azure function?

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

Is there any way to consume multiple service bus messages at a time in the service bus-triggered azure function?

Currently, my azure service bus triggers for single message in the service bus topic. Since I am getting a huge number of messages, I would like to process them all at a time.

Comment: Please see the docs: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.servicebus-readme?view=azure-dotnet#batch-triggers

Answer (score 2):

We had similar requirement at our end, and we solved it using following approach.

**There are 2 ways you can receive message from the queue/topic.**

1. Using `ServiceBusProcessorClient`
2. Using `ServiceBusReceiverClient`

Using 2nd option, we can specify the number of messages we want to read from queue, using it's method `public IterableStream<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> peekMessages(int maxMessages)`

```
ServiceBusReceiverClient receiver = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
    .connectionString(connectionString)
    .receiver()
    .queueName(queueName)
    .buildClient(); // In general we create client like this, if using connection string

IterableStream<ServiceBusReceivedMessage> messages = receiver.peekMessages(10);
```

**PS:**
In case you want to know number of messages in the queue/topic, and the use it as number of messages to peek from queue, you can create an instance of `ServiceBusAdministrationClient` and get the the count like this -

```
serviceBusAdministrationClient.getQueueRuntimeProperties(queueName).getActiveMessageCount()
```